# Extract Sample start value from Sampler result tab in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I need to extract "Sample start" value means date & time value from the Sampler result tab in JMeter.

```
Sample Start:2022-07-13 21:56:18 IST
Load time:1549
Connect Time:292
```

Is there any way to do that? Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which start time you want to "extract" and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
vars.put('start', new Date(prev.getStartTime()).format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz'))
```

it will store the parent Sampler start time into `${start}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Demo:

[image]

More information on what do these `prev` and `vars` things mean: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri for your valuable comment.